# Javascript - Custom Prototype - Syntax Error

Tags: javascript, prototype

I am trying to develop a custom prototype in Javascript(please see code below).

This code works fine if I replace the **₹** character with **$** character. However, I prefer using **₹** character over **$** character. If I use **₹** character I get the below error message:

> Uncaught SyntaxError: Invalid or unexpected token

Is there any way or workaround to make the below code work with **₹** character?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en-IN">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" /> 
<script>
    function ₹(input){
        this.input=input;
        var customPrototype={};
        customPrototype.upper=function(){
            return input.toUpperCase();
        }
        customPrototype.count=function(){
            return input.length;
        };
        customPrototype.lower=function(){
            return input.toLowerCase();
        }
        customPrototype.__proto__ = ₹.prototype;
        customPrototype.constructor = ₹;
        return customPrototype;
    }
    ₹.prototype = {
        top: function() {
            return this.upper();
        },
        size: function() {
            return this.count();
        },
        bottom: function() {
            return this.lower();
        }
    };
</script>
</head>
<body>
    <script>
        console.log(₹("ProgrAmmeR").top());
        console.log(₹("ProgrAmmeR").bottom());
        console.log(₹("ProgrAmmeR").size());
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I'm not quite sure, but have you double checked whether the actual file is saved ad UTF-8?

Comment: clearly the ₹ isn't as powerful as the $ :p

Answer (score 5, accepted):

JavaScript allows a wide range of characters in identifiers ([details in the spec here](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/7.0/index.html#sec-names-and-keywords)). The *first* character of an identifier is a bit more restricted than the subsequent ones, but still allows a lot of freedom.

The first character must be `$`, `_`, or a Unicode character with the "ID_Start" property according to the Unicode standard ([spec link](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/7.0/index.html#prod-UnicodeIDStart)). [The character ₹](http://unicode.org/cldr/utility/character.jsp?a=20B9) doesn't have ID_Start, so you can't use it as the first character of a JavaScript identifier.

Subsequent characters must be `$`, `_`, or a Unicode character with the "ID_Continue" property. FWIW, you couldn't use that character in an identifier at all, because it doesn't have ID_Continue, either.

So why is `$` (a dollar sign) allowed when `₹` (a Rupee sign) and other currency symbols like `£`, `€`, `¥`, and such are not? Purely because Brendan Eich thought it would be useful to allow `$` in identifiers and made an exception for it.

You could use `Rs` if you liked. Not as good, but...

```
function Rs() { }
Rs.prototype = ...;
```

Comment: There's also [this useful tool](https://mothereff.in/js-variables) which validates Unicode variable names. (It does indeed confirm that [`₹`](https://mothereff.in/js-variables#%E2%82%B9) is not a valid variable name.)

Comment: @Frxstrem - I tested the code with the default name `ಠ_ಠ` shown in that URL and it works fine. Unfortunately, the character I prefer is not valid :(

Comment: T.J Crowder - The links you've mentioned in your post seems to be unavailable at this moment.

Comment: @Programmer: I think it must be your connection, they're all up for me and for http://downforeveryoneorjustme.com/.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder - It's up now. Thank you for your explanation.